# Calculate percentage for single record in SQLITE

Tags: android, sqlite, aggregate-functions, percentage

I have `Register` table and in this I have following fields like:

`r_id , f_name , l_name , isactive , pkg`

**pkg** field can have values of 1,2,3,4. I want to find out percentage of how many user has `pkg` value 1 and 2 and 3 and 4.
I used following query, but it is not work for me.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt ,SUM(r_id) as sumSales ,AVG(r_id)*100 as avgSales
FROM reg where pkg=1
```

Comment: do you mean that they have all the 4 packages or do you want individual values of each pkg type.

Comment: MDMalik : Yes that is i want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following code

```
SELECT pkg,ROUND((count(*)*100)/(SELECT count(*) FROM reg)) as percentage
FROM reg group by pkg
```

Try is yourself on [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/f20d1/1/0)

Comment: MDMalik :Ya perfect!!

Answer (score 0):

If i have to do this on web, i'll go this way..

```
SELECT pkg,ROUND((count(*)/(SELECT count(*) FROM register))*100) as percentage FROM `register` group by pkg
```

Hope it will work on Android as well ;)

Comment: Mukesh Rana :  i tried your query but it gave me 0 percentage in all case